# How to get all li tags within the class in the elements array in Jsoup

Tags: java, dom, jsoup

I want to extract all `li` tags within the specific class `div` using `Jsoup`. 
 Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Elements ele=doc.getElementsByClass("div.solution>div#li");
String text="";
for (Element x : ele) {
    text= text.concat(x.text()+"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
element.select("div[class=yourClass]")
```

Comment: Could u elaborate more ...What i needed was that i wanna select all the li tags within the specific class ........

Comment: @hex what exactly you need help with? The code above will select all `div` elements with specific class tag. If you want `li` change it for `li`. Which part are you having problems with. And keep in mind, StackOverflow is not an entrance-level help site, nor is it a training manual. You are supposed to show an effort in researching your problem as well as showing what steps you took and what specifically doesn't work

Comment: sorry sir ,I misinterpreted the solution u gave ,,,,Thanks

Comment: Let me know if that worked for you. And in this case consider marking answer as correct